# Creating a custom Stat object in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to create a custom Stat object for ggplot2. (Specifically I'd like to create a smoother that works differently than the ones `stat_smooth` allows- for instance, without a `y~x` modeling function- but there are other custom Stats I'd like to create even if there were a workaround for my specific case).

I found [this suggested solution from Hadley Wickham](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-November/146067.html):

```
StatExpo <- proto(Stat, {
  objname <- "expo"
  desc <- "Exponential smoothing"
  default_geom <- function(.) GeomLine

  calculate_groups <- function(., data, scales, variable="x", ...) {
    data$y <- HoltWinters(data$x, ...)
  }
})
stat_expo <- StatExpo$new
```

However, when I try it I get:

```
Error in proto(Stat, { : object 'Stat' not found
```

Upon looking around the [ggplot code](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2), I found [where Stat is defined](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-.r). However, the `Stat` object is, as far as I can tell, [never exported from ggplot2](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/NAMESPACE).

I could write my new stat object within the `ggplot2/R` folder and then reinstall the package, but obviously this would be cumbersome and make the solution very difficult to share with others. How can I create a custom Stat object outside of the ggplot namespace?

Comment: does `ggplot2:::Stat` help?

Comment: @baptiste Nope, `Error: 'Stat' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggplot2'`. Does it work for you?

Comment: it works with three `:::`

Comment: @baptiste Ah! I misread. That works; please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ggplot2:::Stat` can be used to access the non-exported object.

Comment: Needing ::: will prevent a user-defined function from being included in a package to be submitted to CRAN, unfortunately.  CRAN checks do not allow :::.

Answer (score 1):

```
getFromNamespace('Stat','ggplot2')
```